# atom editor show invisible shows non-gray dot

Tags: atom-editor

My Atom.io editor is great but with one recent funny appearing after I tick the configuration to show: invisible characters.

Instead of 4 gray dots as spaces, it shows 3 gray and one orange dot, which I would think it is non-space character.

Is there any configuration I missed?

[image]